# apprent error in command line help cl.exe version 12.00.8186?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I need to find out if there is a problem with cl.exe version 12.00.8186 in general
Every once in a while the command line i put in either by hand or from makefiles are being
incorrecly processed. I havent been able to prove that there is an actual error going on until now, I will what happens when I do a simple request for help on the command line:

```
c:\vc\bin>cl /?
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12.00.8168 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1998. All rights reserved.

Command line warning D4002 : ignoring unknown option '/r'
Command line warning D4002 : ignoring unknown option '/~'
Command line error D2003 : missing source filename
c:\vc\bin>_
```

BUT. if I enter this:

```
c:\vc\bin>cl /help
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12.00.8168 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1998. All rights reserved.

                          C/C++ COMPILER OPTIONS  ..more help follows
```

Now this wouldn't bother me except in the text given back when using /help there is this:

```
                              -MISCELLANEOUS-

/?, /help print this help message       <------ actual text from using /help
```

..Showing that /? was supposed to be the primary way to invoke help. Furthermore, I get similar (seemingly random) responses with other commands *sometimes* which makes any other example hard to reproduce but I am sure they are there. So my questions are, what is causing this? is there a workaround? does this cause other problems with other commands as well? is there any place where all these problems are documented??
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: note: i have since moved on to gcc, my frustrations with windows and microsoft has reached it's limit, even though I have learned tons of useful information about their tools and whatnot, I can only use these  for professional purposes. For private purposes, I am now using gcc and it so far exhibits stability not to mention easily fixed bugs through a tight and concise dialoge between users and developers which I've found is pretty normal for the open source community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Best Guess

The best guess I can give to myself is that ? is a wildcard, and somehow / was interpreted as a pathname separator instead of a parameter, given the output of the response and looking back. It looks like filenames may be considered before parameters, but since it is closed source, there is no way to ever tell, save the bit of testing that I did do.

There were files in that directory that contained those characters, and they did change depending on where the executable was fired from, so that was the only confirmation I got that this was the best guess.

The question cannot be answered any further than this unless the guy who wrote the source code actually comes on here and answers.

### Conclusion

Actually, I think pigs will probably fly and Ralph Nader will become president of the United States before that happens.

Comment: Nice pov. And congrats also by your posture hereBravo